# How many four coloured balls are there in a bag

Tags: probability

How many four coloured balls are there in a bag, such that all but $12$ are blue, all but $21$ are black, all but $20$ are red  and all but $19$ are green

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You have 5 equations and 5 variables:
$$
x+12=T \\
y+21=T\\
z+20=T\\
a+19=T\\
x+y+z+a=T
$$

Solve for T by plugging in the first four to the last.

Comment: Last step can be thought of as adding the first four equations 'column-wise' in which case we have $T + 72 = 4T$.